# How do i get friendly url in php only?

Tags: php, friendly-url

I've wrote function in php

```
function siteContent() {
    $path = array();

    $strDefaultPath = '/sites/';

    $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] = isset( $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ) ? $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] : $strDefaultPath;

    $path = explode( '/', substr( $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], 1) );

    if(file_exists('/'.$path['0'].'.php')) {
        require_once('/'.$path['0'].'.php');
    } else {
        require_once('sites/main.php');
    }
}
```

it doesn't work

in menu links looks like this http://site.com/subsite/
but path to the files with content of subsites looks likt this public_html/sites/subsite.php

can i rewrite url with this function or

how can i rewrite or build that urls in php only

i'm beginnier in php

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use a .htaccess file? If you are using apache then it's supported.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve with your code... `require` will not change the URL. As far as I know there is no way to rewrite URLs using PHP.

Comment: i've got contract with hoster wich doesn't allow to use htaccess

Comment: In your position I would change hosting provider.. I don't know even one provider witch would disallow that..

Comment: this isn't that simple and for about 23 moths i've got to use this provider :/

Answer (score 1):

If you work with Apache, the best way is to use a .htaccess file to make URL rewriting.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

[URL Rewriting for Beginners](http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)

Comment: i can't use mod rewrite so i posted this question :P

Comment: Ok but it was not explicit enough, you said you were a beginner in php ;)